# Usage of ng-repeat for two different arrays - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

### I have 2 set of arrays.

Ex: 
$scope.names = ['John', 'Tyler', 'David']; &  $scope.ages = ['30', '35', '28'];

### The output exactly i want is

John: 30
Tyler: 35
David: 28

I have tried as below,

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <div ng-repeat="age in ages">
   <p>{{age}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i am not getting the values properly. As i am new to angularjs, i searched a lot in internet. Any help?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have an object person and do person.name and person.age?

Comment: @Jakub - Yes. But the array, i am getting from webservice. i dont have control on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $index:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
  <p>{{name}}:{{ages[$index]}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... a line code... i spended more than one hour. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If the length of both array will be same then you can make single object of both the arrays and use that object in ng-repeat.
Here is the snippet:

```
$scope.person = {};

angular.forEach($scope.names, function(value, key) {
  $scope.person.name = value;
  $scope.person.ages = $scope.age[key];
}, log);
```

Hope it'll help you.